# how to install fiona on a newly generated github codespace?

Tags: gdal, linux, fiona

This question as been asked multiple times here and on SO but it seems anything related to GDAL in the python realm requires special care on any new environment. So here is the Github codespace one.

I want to use geopandas in a lib and it works just fine on my computer. For technical reasons I cannot afford to use conda so I'll stick to the pip installation.

The environment I'm using to create the codespace is the following:

```
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python",
  "postCreateCommand": "python -m pip install nox pre-commit && pre-commit install"
}
```

It's a linux machine with x86_64 architecture and Python 3.10 installed.

Now if I try to run `pip install fiona` I get the following error:

```
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.9.4.post1.tar.gz (924 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      <string>:86: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' function is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
      WARNING:root:Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
      CRITICAL:root:A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
      [end of output]
```

From my understanding, fiona was shipped with the binary wheels for gdal for both Mac and Linux platform. Then why is it not found during the installation process ?
Is there anything else I should do ?

Comment: Have you tried to pip install the linux wheel directly? `python -m pip install  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/b9/c3821af48b949f8db275dc5bf0d66fd4cb6a492cd96d3f427bced20945ae/Fiona-1.9.4.post1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856) for the hint.

It seems use bare pip is not playing nice in the codespace environment so instead use:

```
python -m pip install fiona
```

which will work just fine.

PS: I didn't take the time to understand why bare pip was not working but if anyone wants to improve this answer, please edit it.